# Determine if an image is cached in browser (either memory or disk cache) before displaying the image?

Tags: javascript, image, google-chrome, browser-cache, http-caching

For lazy-loading visualization, I'm attempting to apply a fade-in animation style class only to images that **have not** been cached in the browser.

To determine if an image was previously loaded and cached in the browser, we can employ the **[HTMLImageElement.complete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement/complete)** property in a function like this:

```
const isImageCached = (imageSource) => {

    let image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSource;

    const isCached = image.complete;
    image.src = "";
    image = null;
    
    return isCached;
};
```

However, in Chrome, HTTP Cache items are either located in `memory cache` or `disk cache`.  The above function only works if the image is in `memory cache` and will always return false if the image is in `disk cache`.  I assume this is because memory is accessed immediately at 0 milliseconds while the disk cache can take up to several milliseconds to be retrieved.

**[Code Test (JSFiddle)](https://jsfiddle.net/tapeu0w9/)**

When you first open and run the above script the image fades in since it hasn't yet been cached in the browser.  When you re-run the script by pressing the **"Run"** button, the image doesn't fade in because it is now cached in Chrome's `memory cache`.  The problem occurs if the memory cache has been cleared.  The image has already been cached but now it may be located in the `disk cache` so the image will fade in.

Below is a screen capture of Chrome Developer Tools detailing the output when the page is refreshed (`disk cache`) and then the script is re-run without a page refresh (`memory cache`):

[image: Chrome DevTools Screen Capture]

Is it possible to determine in JavaScript if an image is located in the HTTP Cache, either `memory cache` or `disk cache`, before displaying the image?

```js
const image = document.querySelector("img");
const marioSrc = "https://www.pinclipart.com/picdir/big/361-3619269_mario-16-bit-mario-bros-super-mario-world.png";

const isImageCached = (imageSource) => {

    let image = new Image();
    image.src = imageSource;

    const result = image.complete;
    image.src = "";
    image = null;
    
    return result;
};

if (!isImageCached(marioSrc)) {
    image.classList.add("image-fade-in");
}

image.setAttribute("src", marioSrc);
```

```css
:root {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

body {
    background-color: #444444;
    height: 100vh;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    overflow-y: hidden;
}

@keyframes fade-in {

    0%   { opacity: 0; }
    100% { opacity: 1; }
}

.image-fade-in {
    animation: fade-in 1s ease-in-out;
}
```

```html
<img />
```

Comment: I remember some "exploit" that would do it by checking load times, <1 ms

Comment: Even if an image is cached, decoding it may still take time.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Setting a specific wait time to determine if an image is in the browser disk cache is required, and while most of the time it's a very small wait time (<5 milliseconds), the value can fluctuate dramatically depending on the event loop stack and hardware.

This can be accomplished by racing promises:  a loading image vs. a timeout.

For my specific use-case, if an image loads in under 25ms I can assume it's cached, otherwise I'll assume it has never been loaded and apply the fade-in style.

```
const promiseTimeout = (ms, promise, timeoutMessage = null) => {

    let timerID;

    const timer = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

        timerID = setTimeout(() => reject(timeoutMessage), ms);
    });

    return Promise
        .race([ promise, timer ])
        .then((result) => {

            clearTimeout(timerID);

            return result;
        });
};

const imageURL = "https://dummyimage.com/600x400/000/fff.png&text=a";
let image = new Image();
    
const imageComplete = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    image.onload = () => resolve(image);
    image.onError = () => reject(image);
    
    image.src = imageURL;
});

promiseTimeout(25, imageComplete, "Not loaded from cache")
    .then((result) => console.log("Loaded from cache:", result))
    .catch((error) => {
        
        image.src = "";
        image = null;
        
        console.log(error);
    });
```